# Why is my cpu never using its turbo frequency

Tags: windows-10, performance, turbo-boost

My laptops (hp elitebook 850 g5) Processor (i7-8550) is suppose to be able to go up to 4 GHz but it never does (according to the task manager) even if its working at 100%.
Why is that?
(I'm using win 10)
[image]

Comment: Based on the screenshot your system is being thermally throttled.

Comment: This was happening to me.  In my case.. I didn't have the right OEM power supply! :^P

Comment: Three things: 1) I had a different but similar HP elite book.In its firmware (UEFI) turbo was turned off to extend battery life. Check that first.  2) As Mokubai already wrote: CPU do not run at turrbo all the time. Instead it is like reserve energy when sprinting, you can briefly do it but then you fall back to your regular max dissipated heat. Max load on all cores should stabilise in no turbo after T1 time. (Where t1 usually is about 30 second, but is configurable).  3). DELL laptop ran intentionally slow if you did not use an Dell charger. Not sure if HP ever did the same.

Answer (score 5):

The 4GHz turbo is only if 1 core is working hard and the other cores are essentially idle (thus generating little heat). In this case the single core will boost up until it meets the thermal limits of the CPU. With all cores working turbo boost will boost a lot less.

With different numbers of cores active, and potentially depending on the diversity of instructions being used, you will get different peak clock speeds.

Judging by your CPU graph the entire CPU is in use very heavily. As a result you may only get a minimal overclock due to the processor already being near its thermal limit.

Looking at your performance graphs you are also using the Intel UHD graphics, which will be in the same package as your CPU. That will also be contributing to your thermal limit and preventing your CPU from boosting higher. Changing to use the Radeon graphics may not change much (and may make things worse due to it being higher power) as many laptops share a heatsink/heatpipe assembly between the CPU, GPU and fan.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost)

> The increased clock rate is limited by the processor's power, current, and thermal limits, the number of cores currently in use, and the maximum frequency of the active cores.
>
> When any electrical or thermal limits are exceeded, the operating frequency automatically decreases in decrements of 133 or 100 MHz until the processor is again operating within its design limits.